# Get id of parent element of currently clicked element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How do I get the id of a parent element of currently clicked element in AngularJS?

```
<div id="d8" class="menutitles ng-scope" ng-repeat="title in list">
     <div class="right" ng-click="showsubmenu($event)">+</div>
     <div class="left" ng-click="showsubmenu($event)">Unit 9</div>
</div>
```

How to get the  value **d8** in `showsubmenu($event)` function?

Below is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
$scope.showsubmenu=function(obj)
{
    alert(obj.target.parent.attributes.id)
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It should be `parentNode`, not just `parent`:

```
alert(obj.target.parentNode.id);
```

Also `attributes` is redundant as you can access `id` property directly.

But note, that since you have `ngRepeat`, it will create invalid markup, since ids are going to be duplicated. You probably want to fix this too, maybe like this or use classes:

```
<div id="d8{{$index}}" class="menutitles ng-scope" ng-repeat="title in list">
    <div class="right" ng-click="showsubmenu()">+</div>
   <div class="left" ng-click="showsubmenu()">Unit 9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any more 'ANGULARish' way to do this?

Comment: @TusharShukla Sure. You could crate two directives, like `<menu-list>` and child `<menu-item>`. Then child directive would register with its parent controller. But to me it's much more complex solution and not worth it.

Comment: It's a pity debug session (in WebStorm) doesn't show these things.

Answer (score 9):

```
<div id="d8" class="menutitles ng-scope" ng-repeat="title in list">
    <div class="right" ng-click="showsubmenu()">+</div>
   <div class="left" ng-click="showsubmenu()">Unit 9</div>
</div>
```

It should be enough :D

```
function showsubmenu($event){
    $($event.target).parent();

}
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Pedro's answer I'd say that using the [jQuery method `closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) would be preferable.

```
function showsubmenu($event){
    var parent = $($event.target).closest('.yourclass'); // or any selector you prefer
}
```